# datatables recalculate scroll on hide columns

Tags: jquery, scroll, width, datatables, fixed

i'm using the datatables plugin of http://datatables.net/ and the plugin for fixedColumns.
I have a table of a lot of columns, so i decided to use scrollX and and option to hide some columns.
The problem is that when i hide some columns, the plugin recalculate the width of my columns (i supposed it want to adjust the columns to the scrollX, so it increases the width of my columns), how i have 3 fixed columns, the width of this columns increases and i want to hold that columns.

also the plugin doesn't respect my width config, i don't know what's going on but it doesn't work good.

I want to know if somebody has a concept about it, some advice or something that i'm ignoring or the reason about this situation.

```js
var columndefs = [{targets: 0,searchable: false,width: "26px","cellType": "th"},
            {targets: [1,2],searchable: true,width: "170px","visible": true},
            {targets: targets,searchable: false,'orderable': false,width: "60px","type": html","visible": true}];
var datatable = $('#gradestable').DataTable( {
        scrollX: true,
        paging: false,
        iDisplayLength: 50,
        columnDefs: columndefs,
        bAutoWidth:false,
        autoWidth: false,
        oLanguage: {
            "sProcessing": "{{ lang('table_processing') }}",
            "sLengthMenu": "{{ lang('table_recordsperpage') }}",
            "sZeroRecords": "{{ lang('table_noregisters') }}",
            "sEmptyTable": "{{ lang('table_empty') }}",
            "sInfo": "{{ lang('table_pager') }}",
            "sInfoEmpty": "{{ lang('table_pagerempty') }}",
            "sInfoFiltered": "{{ lang('table_filtered') }}",
            "sSearch": "{{ lang('table_search') }}",
            "sLoadingRecords": "{{ lang('table_loading') }}",
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": "{{ lang('table_sortAsc') }}",
                "sSortDescending": "{{ lang('table_sortDesc') }}",
            },
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "{{ lang('table_first') }}",
                "sLast": "{{ lang('table_last') }}",
                "sNext": "{{ lang('table_next') }}",
                "sPrevious": "{{ lang('table_previous') }}",
            },
        }
    } );
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( datatable, {leftColumns:3,heightMatch: "auto"});
```

the variable

```
targets
```

that is used to define the column properties is an array of numbers, somthing like [3,4,5,6,7] it's variable becouse the columns are variables.

thanks